# Error {DynamicResource resourcename}' value is not a valid MarkupExtension expression

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010, i was editing WPF form in Expression Blend, and suddenly i have started getting following compile time errors, the project works on other machines but not on my machine. All machines have same version of .net 4

I am getting hundreds of errors and following is one of them

```
         Error  115 '{DynamicResource alternateRowColours}' value is not a valid
         MarkupExtension expression. Cannot resolve 'DynamicResource' in namespace 
         'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'. 'DynamicResource'  
         must be a subclass of MarkupExtension. Line 8 Position 32. C:\Projects
         \Dev\Projects\Edge3\trunk\src\Edge3\UI\BrowsePage\DetailPanel
         \ApplicantLettingsDetailPanel_Owners.xaml
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the following link.

http://www.vbforums.com/archive/index.php/t-627148.html